# how to set a default value in DevExpress GridColumn

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I have the following scenario :

```
    private DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemComboBox repository;
    private DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn colMaster;
```

.

```
     this.colMaster.ColumnEdit = this.repository;
```

.

```
     repository.Items.Clear();
     repository.Items.AddRange(i_masters);
```

i want to have the first value of i_masters set as default. Now it's an empty box.

Can anyone please help?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience you can't set the default value of the repository item. The only way to do that is to set the value of your datasource properties to the value you want in the comboBox. Or if its an unbound column to use the `CustomUnboundColumnData` event to set the value.   So that you are basically setting the cell value which happens to match what you want in the repositoryItemComboBox.

For example:

```
List<whatever> list = new List<whatever>();

foreach (whatever item in list) {
    item.property = repository.Items(0);
}
```

This seems to be backed up by this [issue](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q139821.aspx) on the devExpress site.